# Change Height and Width of TextArea in codemirror

Tags: javascript

I am developing website which having xml, java programs. So i chose CodeMirror for displaying programs in TextArea. I had successfully displayed. It's default `height` is `300px` in `codemirror.css`. How to change Height and Width of TextArea programmatically in codemirror?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

[The CodeMirror user manual is your friend.](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#setSize)

Example code:

```
<textarea id="myText" rows="4" cols="10"></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var myTextArea = document.getElementById('myText');
    var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(myTextArea);
    myCodeMirror.setSize(500, 300);
</script>
```

Answer (score 25):

```
myCodeMirror.setSize(null, 500);
```

You can pass null for either of them to indicate that that dimension should not be changed.

[Documentation:](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html)

```
cm.setSize(width: number|string, height: number|string)
```

> Programmatically set the size of the editor (overriding the applicable
>   CSS rules). width and height can be either numbers (interpreted as
>   pixels) or CSS units ("100%", for example). You can pass null for
>   either of them to indicate that that dimension should not be changed.

Answer (score 18):

Although the answer from Christian is great, just a heads up:

> Autoresize Demo.

```
.CodeMirror {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  height: auto;
}
```

> By setting an editor's `height` style to `auto` and giving the `viewportMargin` a value of `Infinity`, CodeMirror can be made to automatically resize to fit its content.

Source: https://codemirror.net/demo/resize.html

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't work with other values than `auto`

Comment: Autoresize wasn't working for me.  Through the process of elimination, I determined that having '<!doctype html>' is important for Autoresize to work.  Otherwise, it will make your CodeMirror instance the full height of the page.

Answer (score 4):

As an extention to the correct answer:

If you want that it **takes the whole size of the Parent element**, you can use:

`myCodeMirror.setSize("100%", "100%");`

Answer (score 1):

if you are doing this in react use `ref`

```
const codemirrorRef = React.useRef();

React.useEffect(() => {
  const current = codemirrorRef.current.editor.display.wrapper.style.height = "1000px";
});

<CodeMirror
    [...]           
    ref={codemirrorRef}
/>
```

`codemirrorRef.current.editor.display.wrapper` contains the div element. From there you can do anything you would do if you did `document.getElementById('#id')`

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function () {
   // CodeMirror
   CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("codeMirrorDemo"), {
      lineNumbers: true,
      readOnly: true,
      //mode: "htmlmixed",
   }).setSize("100%", 610);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the solutions above but always struggled with the option when one line was too long and then it break out of the wrapper and broke the layout. I did not want to use the lineBreak option so I defined following:

```
<div class="container">
  <textarea id="codemirror">
</div>
```

and the style was following:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: {as you want}
  width: 100%;
}

#codemirror {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use ngx-codemirror package in your angular application the below blog will be very much useful for you

https://devsuhas.com/2021/04/06/change-height-and-width-of-textarea-in-codemirror/